# I have just been charged $134.53 for Google cloud Managed DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I know this is not the place for it but Google cloud have absolutely no guides as to why I'd be charged that much for a domain that's hosted with them, I need to understand what happened so I wouldn't find a charge again tomorrow... I have one domain hosted with Google cloud as I was trying it out and it's pointing to an instance inside Google cloud, I'm not pointing to an outside website somewhere. PLEASE HELP

**Edit:**
Google has replied to my support ticket much sooner than expected and their reply was:

After reviewing the information you provided, we believe that you may be affected by a known issue.  Here are some details about the issue:

Description:
Some customers may notice that their expected monthly bill for Cloud DNS is higher than expected.

How to diagnose:
If you look at the estimated monthly usage for Cloud DNS you may notice that it is higher than you expected. If this is the case, you may be effected.

Workaround:
There's no workaround available at this time, but we'll let you know if we learn of one.

We have identified the problem that was causing incorrect reporting of Cloud DNS usage, and it has been resolved.  We are currently working on reversing these charges.

I will leave this here in case anyone else faces this issue so they wouldn't panic as I did.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 7):

Google has replied to my support ticket much sooner than expected and their reply was:

After reviewing the information you provided, we believe that you may be affected by a known issue.  Here are some details about the issue:

Description:
Some customers may notice that their expected monthly bill for Cloud DNS is higher than expected.

How to diagnose:
If you look at the estimated monthly usage for Cloud DNS you may notice that it is higher than you expected. If this is the case, you may be effected.

Workaround:
There's no workaround available at this time, but we'll let you know if we learn of one.

We have identified the problem that was causing incorrect reporting of Cloud DNS usage, and it has been resolved.  We are currently working on reversing these charges.

I will leave this here in case anyone else faces this issue so they wouldn't panic as I did.