# Managed Zone of Google Cloud DNS keep increasing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I have 2,640.47 ManagedZone-month according to Billing, while I supposed to have only 2.

How can I decrease ManagedZone-month?

```
name-iMac:project name$ gcloud dns managed-zones list
NAME     DNS_NAME      DESCRIPTION
p_1      p_1.com.
p_2      p_2.tv.

name-iMac:project name$ gcloud dns project-info describe  project   
id: project
kind: dns#project
number: '8...'
quota:
  kind: dns#quota
  managedZones: 10000
  resourceRecordsPerRrset: 100
  rrsetAdditionsPerChange: 100
  rrsetDeletionsPerChange: 100
  rrsetsPerManagedZone: 10000
  totalRrdataSizePerChange: 10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with Cloud DNS incorrectly reporting usage and affecting the billing. [Google are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823955/i-have-just-been-charged-134-53-for-google-cloud-managed-dns) on resolution and reverting these changes.

Comment: Thanks DoIT International!